# How would I go about creating a constructor to initialize one char from a custom String class?

Tags: c++

I have a custom string class that has one private member to hold the string (char* str_arr), so when I make a string in main I do String str = "This is a string!". My constructor for that is as follows:

```
String::String(const char* data): str_arr(nullptr)
{
    if (data != nullptr)
    {
        str_arr = new char[strlen(data) + 1];
        strcpy(str_arr, data);
    }
}
```

My problem is I have to make a constructor for my String classs that takes a char. So in main I could say, char ch = 'y' then String str = ch and that would work. I'm just not really sure how to do this and can't get my head around it. I can't just say

```
String::String(char data)
{
    char temp = data;
}
```

because that wouldn't transfer the memory  to my private str_array variable. And I can't say

```
String::String(char data)
{
    char* temp = new char(data) + 1;
    temp = data;
    str_array = temp;
}
```

because temp is a char*  and data is a char. I need pointed in the right direction. I can provide more information if need be, I'm fairly new to programming. Thank you!

*edit: I've already looked a lot about this issue and tried to find something similar with no luck. If I am missing something, please feel free to point it out.

Comment: Maybe `str_array = new char[2]{data, '\0'};` is what you are looking for?  Since your string class is based around `char*`s you have to make sure you include a null terminator.

Comment: It is not necessary to repeat tag information in the title of your post. The tagging system works extremely well and doesn't need additional help. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated: `delete[] str_arr;` immediately after setting after `str_arr` to `nullptr` should be stripped from the program by the compiler because it doesn't do anything, but it still looks kind of silly. There's no point `delete`ing before it's possible to have allocated anything.

Comment: thanks @user4581301 honestly not sure why I had that there to begin with.

Comment: @0x5453 that makes sense, thank you. The problem is with that way it is still conflicting that str_array is char* and data is just a char. That's where I was trying to go with  char* temp = new char(data) + 1; then find a way to copy it over but I could be missing your point. I'll keep looking though